# Xampp - PHP Imagick does not work with Ghostscript in local

Tags: php, file, pdf, imagick

I successfully installed Imagick version 3.4.4 on PHP 7.2.18 in my XAMPP for windows 10.
I tried to launch the phpinfo.php file and I see correctly configured imagick.

My site is with Magento 1.9.4.3.
I'm on the client account page and I just tried to run this code to see if imagick exists and everything works fine:

```
if (class_exists('imagick')) {echo "imagick exist";} else {echo "class imagick not exist";}
```

After this I installed ghostscript 9.50 for win 32. I installed ghostscript in the main root of xampp. After the installation of Ghostscript too I immediately tried to have a pdf file read in this way and unfortunately the page returns blank:

```
$Filename = Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'clienti'.DS.$customerName.DS."flooop.pdf";

$im = new imagick();
$im->readImage($Filename);
```

The error I saw from the var / log / exception.log file is this:

```
ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `system cannot find the file specified.

' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/794 in C:\xampp\htdocs\higiftit\app\design\frontend\sns_toronto\default\template\customer\upload\area-invio-file.phtml:186
```

I tried everything but unfortunately the same error always returns.
How could I do?

Comment: Seems like PATH is wrong, can you try to edit with path like(`$Filename =/path/to/floop.pdf`)?

Comment: var_dump $Filename. Then paste that file into your windows explorer. I'm guessing it will be in the wrong place and you just need to tweak your path

Comment: I think the path is correct. I tried with var_dump($Filename) and the result is: string(52) "C:\xampp\htdocs\higiftit\clienti\John Doe\flooop.pdf"

Comment: @Gabriel91 I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?